# How to change the TWBS popover's height dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a problem that about change a popover's height dynamically.

Say, I have a button, and there will be popover shown up if I clicked the button, besides the popover has a default css height value, let's say '600px'. so if I click the button then the popover shown up with a height of '600px'. But I want to change the popover's height dynamically according to the viewport's size. Below is the function I wrote, and it will fire up after the page is loaded.

```
function calculatePopoverHeight() {
    var viewPortHeight = $(window).height();
    var popoverHeight = viewPortHeight - 10;
    var popoverContentHeight = popoverHeight - 5;

    $('.popover').css('height', popoverHeight + 'px');
    $('.popover-content').css('height', popoverContentHeight + 'px');
};
```

But this doesn't work, I believe the reason is that when the function is fired up, the popover wasn't in the DOM, so the jQuery can't get the element. But I want the value to be ready before the popover shown up.
So if anyone has ran into this? Or if you have any idea?

Comment: Do you know you can use `vh` in combination with `calc()` to do these same calculations in CSS? Re: your problem, it would help if you included all of your code and a way for us to easily replicate it.

Comment: Hi @MichaelCoker , thanks for your hint I will try it out!